# tkinter button in class won't bind to key

Tags: python, button, tkinter, bind

Total noob can't make tkinter button bind to keyboard.

I've tried to bind they  both in main() and in the **init**().

I've tried bunches of permutations of syntax. Nothing works.

I've tried  around until the button(s) get focus and hitting  then. NOTHING HAPPENS.

Anyone have the secret insider information on how to do it?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Button, Style

class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.btn_convert.bind("<Return>", self.convert)
    # -----------------------------------------------

    def convert(self):
        print("enter pressed")
    # -----------------------------------------------

    def quit(self):
        self.root.destroy()
        exit()
    # -----------------------------------------------

    def initUI(self):

        self.master.title("Weight Converter")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        self.frame_btn = Frame(self)
        self.frame_btn.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=20, pady=5)
        self.btn_convert=Button(self.frame_btn, text="Convert", command=self.convert)
        self.btn_convert.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.btn_close1=Button(self.frame_btn, text="Close", command=quit)
        self.btn_close1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x250+300+200")
    app = Example()
    root.bind("<Return>", lambda event: root.convert())
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Twenty years ago I was developing in M$ Visual Studio. I can't fathom that in 20 years, coding has become less sensible; less straightforward; less-well documented; and less-efficient. In a very short time I'm developing a serious HATRED for Python...

Comment: Is sure looks like Python hates you too!

Comment: @ReblochonMasque it's really kicking my ass...

Comment: Same happens when you replace `bind` with `bind_all`?

Comment: Do you mean like this?        root.bind_all("<Return>", lambda event: app.convert())

Comment: That doesn't do anything, either.

Comment: Just to make sure, you are _not_ getting any errors, and pressing Enter button while the object to `bind` has focus, right?

Comment: @Nae, Yes. I'm looking at the terminal and seeing no errors (and no print of "enter pressed" as should occur. I'm trying first, just pressing <Return>, which yields no activity on the app or in the terminal. Then, I'm clicking in the frame to make sure th app has focus; still no activity in app or terminal. Finally, I'm tabbing until I see the button has focus, and then pressing <Return>; no activity. And, last, I'm tabbing until the other button has focus - and no buttons have focus - and trying <Return> again. All of those experiments yield no activity.

Comment: If I <click> on the button with the mouse, the function fires, printing "enter pressed" in the terminal. No errors. If I <click> on the <close> button, the app closes as expected, again, no errors.

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
root.bind("<Return>", lambda event: root.convert())
```

with:

```
root.bind("<Return>", lambda event: app.convert())
```

or:

```
#in case you have multiple instances of Tk
app.bind("<Return>", lambda event: app.convert())
app.focus_set()
```

As `convert` is a method for `Example` instance(`app`) as opposed to `Tk` instance(`root`). Also, make sure that the `object.bind` is used on(`root` in above two lines and `app` onthe last line) *has* the focus by either manually focusing or calling `object.focus_set()`.

---

Below is an example that `print`s "Enter" or "Escape" based on the keypress:

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Event")
        self.button.bind('<Return>', lambda evt : self.event_handler(True))
        self.button.focus_set()             # ensure initial focus is on the button
        self.button.pack()


    def event_handler(self, is_enter):
        if is_enter:
            my_string = "Enter"
        else:
            my_string = "Escape"
        print(my_string)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.button.bind('<Escape>', lambda evt : app.event_handler(False))
    app.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

---

## Demo Example for all keys

Below demo should be displaying the pressed key for all keys:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


def on_key_press(event):
    global label
    label['text'] = event.keysym


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    label = tk.Label(root)
    root.bind('<KeyPress>', on_key_press)
    label.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I changed it in main() and behavior still the same. No response to <Return>, even if I tab focus to the button.

I changed it in the __init__ and it throws NameError: name 'app' is not defined.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you using IDLE?

Comment: You should point out that this should be done in the `main()` section not the `__init__()`, where the binding would (probably?) have no effect.

Comment: @asongtoruin Well I think it should be clear that the line to be replaced is present only in `main`. In the init it would raise error as `app`s should be replaced with `self`s inside `__init__`.

Comment: I'm using the code that's pasted above. I have NO CLUE about the word you posted. I can't even google a reference for it in any context with python and tkinter and binding.

Comment: How can anyone build anything with a language that has no real documentation?

Comment: @JohnBailey not sure what documentation you're missing - Python is fairly well covered by [the official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/) and Tkinter is at least partially covered at [effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm) in addition to its [section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html) in the main docs.

Comment: @Nae thank you for this: As convert is a method for Example instance(app) as opposed to Tk instance(root). It's helpful toward trying to understand this maddening language. However, the latest edit of the code also still does nothing.

Comment: @asongtoruin I'm not sure what you're finding. I'm looking for a VERY simple straightforward thing: Make a button default to activate it's called function when the <Return> key is pressed. Secondarily, make ANY button call it's function when tabbed into focus and the <Return> key is pressed.  I find ZERO documentation to make such things happen. That's why I'm here. And, there seems not to be a straight and functional answer to this SIMPLE programming need.

Comment: @Nae I think you are asking about an IDE called IDLE? No. I'm using Atom editor and a terminal command line.

Comment: I've got python 3.6.3 and tkinter 8.6, if that means anything.

Comment: @JohnBailey, I agree with you that documentation for Tkinter sucks, otherwise I copy/pasted your code, changed binding to `app.convert()` as also suggested in this answer and it works as expected. There is still some issue when button is focused and you press Enter, but `convert()` is still triggered.

Comment: @JohnBailey Checkout the updated version of the answer.

Comment: @JohnBailey Is this latest version of the Example non-functional as well? I was on phone earlier was unable to test my code.

Comment: @Nae, yes all versions of code presently appearing on this page are non-functional. Both the version you posted above, and the shortened version I pasted below exhibit the same behavior. Mouse events process normally; <tab> key visibly moves focus of objects; <Return> key, regardless of where focus visibly is at the time remains non-functional. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @JohnBailey Above code supposed to bind both Enter and Escape keys, they're both non-functional?

Comment: @JohnBailey Please test your keys with the demo code.

Comment: @Nae, it now works, but the path to that is totally bizarre. I'm going to post an answer. Much, MUCH gratitude to everyone for your help. I'm deeply impressed by this community.

Answer (score 1):

To add a general "press Enter to run `convert`" binding, you should apply it to `root`. To add further focus-based bindings, you should apply them on a per-button basis, like so:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Button, Style

class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
    # -----------------------------------------------

    def convert(self):
        print("enter pressed")
    # -----------------------------------------------

    def quit(self):
        print("quit pressed")
        self.destroy()
        exit()
    # -----------------------------------------------

    def initUI(self):
        self.master.title("Weight Converter")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        self.frame_btn = Frame(self)
        self.frame_btn.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=20, pady=5)
        self.btn_convert=Button(self.frame_btn, text="Convert", command=self.convert)
        self.btn_convert.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.btn_close1=Button(self.frame_btn, text="Close", command=quit)
        self.btn_close1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
        # When tab focus is on the "Close" button, change Return behaviour.
        self.btn_close1.bind("<Return>", lambda event: self.quit())

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x250+300+200")
    app = Example()
    root.bind("<Return>", lambda event: app.convert())
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: OK. Something is wrong. I cut and pasted that code exactly. It does exactly what my other one does. It loads. If I MOUSE CLICK on the button, the function runs. If I hit <Return> nothing happens, even if I tab the focus to the button. My platform is Ubuntu 16.04 gnome, with python 3.6.3 and tkinter 8.6. I'm running this thing from terminal, not an IDE. I can click onto the frame - anything - and it doesn't work. ONLY a mouse click on the actual button works.

Comment: THANK YOU TO EVERYONE for your attempts to help. I'm starting to think I've found a bug in some combination of Python and tkinter. If @asongtoruin is running the code successfully, I don't know what else to think. Thanks again for the generous help.

Comment: @JohnBailey: you haven't found a bug in tkinter.

Comment: @BryanOakley, please explain how you know I haven't found a bug?  Others say this exact code WORKS. However, IT DOES NOT WORK on the platform I detailed (OS, Python and tkinter versions). How can we say there ISN'T a bug, when it works on some foundations and not on others? To me, inconsistent functionality - and non-functionality on some relatively standard platform - is the definition of a bug...

Comment: @JohnBailey: Tkinter is based on tcl/tk. Tcl/tk has been around for a few decades now. Tkinter itself is more than a decade old, and is used by thousands if not tens of thousands of people. If there were a bug in how bindings work, it would have been found and fixed many years ago. It is of course possible that such a bug exists (and I should have said "probably" in my earlier comment), but it's highly unlikely, especially when talking about a unix-like system which is where tcl/tk originated.

Comment: I just tested the code above, and my simplified code below on a desktop (last night was on a laptop). Different machine; identical behavior. (1) I believe this must be a bug. (2) Finding a bug doesn't solve the need to build something. (3) I guess I'm going to have to abandon tkinter as non-working, and try a different GUI base.

Comment: The code in this question works for me, though I don't have the exact combination of software that you do. I'm on ubuntu 14.04 with python 3.5.

Comment: @BryanOakley, Thanks for the help. But, I think the fact that it does work for thousands of people on thousands of platforms further indicates I've found a bug. Otherwise, WHY does it simply not work on the particular platform I'm trying to use it on? I'm not standing on my head. It's not throwing errors. It just doesn't work.

Comment: @JohnBailey When you say it doesn't work, are you first clicking in the window somewhere after it comes up, then pressing the return key, and you don't see anything on stdout in the window where you started it? How _exactly_ are you starting the program? Are you typing `python the_file.py` at a command prompt, or something else?

Comment: I am typing python3 the_file.py at the command prompt in the terminal.

Comment: I am testing every combination of clicking in the frame - and on every part of the thing except the button itself before pressing <Return>. I am tabbing until the button gets focus and then pressing <Return>. I am watching the terminal for errors. None are showing up.

Comment: Thank you again @BryanOakley for your help.  Button clicks with the mouse all produce expected behavior. The <tab> key visibly changes focus, so it's not ignoring kbd altogether. It just won't process the <Return> as bound to the function.

Comment: @JohnBailey: out of curiosity, what if you change the bind statement to `root.bind("<x>", lambda event: app.convert())`, click on the window, and then press the `x` key?

Comment: Also, add this right before calling mainloop: `root.bind("<Any-KeyPress>", lambda event: print(event.keysym))`. Press a few letter keys and it should print out each letter. Press the return key and it should print out `Return`.

Comment: @BryanOakley, it now works, but the path to that is totally bizarre. I'm going to post an answer. Much, MUCH gratitude to everyone for your help. I'm deeply impressed by this community.